# How to pad an array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, split

I am preparing a code that splits a string into arrays of chars and then shuffles each array according to a certain pattern.

I have used some code to split an array to different char arrays according to the "keysize" and it is working fine, except for the last array which might be missing some elements.

If the last array is shorter than other arrays an exception will be thrown because at some point the swapping function might be trying to swap a[0] with a[x] which doesn't exist.

So how can I pad the last array to be the same size?

Here is my splitting code which I found in a question here, where I have edited to use *char* instead of *int*.

```
public static char[][] Split(char[] source, int keysize)
    {
        int fullArrayCount = source.Length / keysize;
        int totalArrayCount = fullArrayCount;
        int remainder = source.Length - (fullArrayCount * keysize);
        if (remainder > 0)
        {
            totalArrayCount++;
        }
        char[][] output = new char[totalArrayCount][];
        for (int i = 0; i < fullArrayCount; i++)
        {
            output[i] = new char[keysize];
            Array.Copy(source, i * keysize, output[i], 0, keysize); // Array.Copy(Original Array,,Target array,"Where to start"0,Howmuch)
        }
        if (totalArrayCount != fullArrayCount)
        {

            output[fullArrayCount] = new char[remainder];
           // output[fullArrayCount] = new char[keysize];
            MessageBox.Show((keysize-remainder).ToString());
            Array.Copy(source, fullArrayCount * keysize,output[fullArrayCount], 0, remainder);

        }
        return output;
    }
```

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, you completely left out the part which actually modifies the array; please include the operation you would like to have done on the elements of `output`.

Comment: I am not sure what do you need, but it seems that your problem is that last array is potentially shorter than the rest? Why just not make it same size as others - keysize, do same Array.Copy as you are doing now, and fill the rest of an array with some default values?

Comment: @NemanjaTodorovic: I think that's the point in the question... OP doesn't know *how* to do that

Comment: @Codor I just want output to become of the same size. other operations are not really relevant here. it will be swapping

Comment: Nice question title. Most probably will be edited away soon.

Comment: @L.Adham Then why not simply use `output[fullArrayCount] = new char[keysize];` in the last case?

Comment: @NemanjaTodorovic Yes i've made the declaration keysize instead of remainder and then tried to find the difference between rwo indeces and add them manually but Array.Copy  threw an exception that the size of array isn't enough

Comment: @L.Adham Is you Array.Copy code for the remainder still the same?

Comment: @NemanjaTodorovic No i changed the last parameter to keysize like this:
Array.Copy(source, fullArrayCount * keysize,output[fullArrayCount], 0, keysize);

Comment: What do you want to pad it with? empty strings?

Comment: @Nikki9696 it doesn't matter anything excepet a letter... so it can be removed later and empty chars are good too :)

Comment: Do you need it returned as a 2 dim array, or is a collection of arrays sufficient?

Comment: @L.Adham you need to leave Array.Copy(source, fullArrayCount * keysize,output[fullArrayCount], 0, reminder) because if you change it to keysize it will try to copy more characters from original array that are not there (it will go out of bounds from original array). You need to fill difference between keysize - reminder manually.

Comment: @NemanjaTodorovic So if i made that change back and used the following function all must work correctly ?
        private char[] padder(char[] array,int size,int desiredsize)
        {
            char[] newarray = new char[desiredsize];
            int dfference = desiredsize - size;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                newarray[i] = array[i];
            for (int j = size; j < desiredsize; j++)
                newarray[j] = '!';
            return newarray;
        }

Comment: I think I have a better way for you. One moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split an array of chars into a collection of arrays of chars of specified lengths, padded with pipe symbols that can be easily replaced/removed/searched for. (it didn't like empty char)

```
public static List<char[]> Split(char[] source, int keysize)
{
    List<char[]> list = new List<char[]>();

    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i+= keysize)
    {
        List<char> c = source.Skip(i).Take(keysize).ToList();
        while (c.Count < keysize)
        {
            c.Add('|');
        }
        list.Add(c.ToArray());
    }
    return list;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var x = Split("abcdefgh".ToCharArray(), 3);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just instead of:

```
output[fullArrayCount] = new char[remainder];
```

write:

```
output[fullArrayCount] = new char[keysize];
```

Comment: i tried this previously, an exception was thrown that there wasn't enough elements. i tried the same code above with creating a loop of (keysize - reminder) times in which a[i] ='!' but the exception was thrown.